# Series of linear maps: on a paper by Evans  and Hanche-Olsen

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, fa.functional-analysis, reference-request

I was reading this [paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0022-1236%2879%2990054-5) by Evans  and Hanche-Olsen. In theorem 2,  there are six equivalent statements given. I write just two of them, which I want to use.

> Let $L$ be a bounded self-adjoint
>   linear map on a unital $C^*$ algebra
>   $\mathcal{A}$. The following
>   conditions are equivalent
>
> (iii) If $y\in\mathcal{A}_+$ (set of
>   positive semi-definite  objects),
>   $a\in\mathcal{A}$ satisfy $ya=0$, then
>   $a^*L(y)a\geq0$.
>
> (iv) For some full invariant set of
>   states $S$ on $\mathcal{A}$, that
>   $y\in\mathcal{A}_+$, $f\in S$ with
>   $f(y)=0$ imply $fL(y)\geq0$.

My question is on condition (iii). If $L$ is a positive map, the condition holds (by definition). However if it is not, what extra condition(s) a general linear bounded map $L$ must satisfy such that condition (iii) holds.

If we replace $\mathcal{A}$ by $\mathcal{B(H)}$ for some Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$ (finite or infinite dimensions) can we find such conditions. If some works are already in literature, please refer. Advanced thanks for any help, suggestions etc.

Comment: Absolutely baffling question.  You have just cited a paper that gives six equivalent versions of this condition.

Comment: Perhaps OP actually wants a class of examples of conditionally positive maps which are not positive?

Comment: @Nik Weaver and @Ollie Margetts The conditions are all equivalent. If $L$ were a conditionally completely positive, from condition (i) $e^{tL}$ becomes completely positive. I wanted to relax the conditionally completely positive criteria, such that (iii) still holds, and I can get, perhaps not a completely positive but a general positive map. 

Comment: 1. Yes, if $L$ is CCP it generates a CP semigroup.
2. Yes you can relax this condition on $L$ to (iii) and, as Evans shows, this is equivalent to the semigroup being positive.
3. I'm afraid I still don't know what you're asking for? Possibly you can edit the question to make this clearer